# pymongo replication secondary readreference not work

Tags: python, mongodb, replication, pymongo

we have MongoDB 2.6 and 2 Replica Set, and we use `pymongo` driver and connect Mongo Replicat Set with the following url

`mongodb://admin:admin@127.0.0.1:10011:127.0.0.1:10012,127.0.0.1:10013/db?replicaSet=replica`

with python code

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
url = 'mongodb://admin:admin@127.0.0.1:10011:127.0.0.1:10012,127.0.0.1:10013/db?replicaSet=replica'
db = 'db'
db = MongoClient(
    url,
    readPreference='secondary',
    secondary_acceptable_latency_ms=1000,
)[db]
db.test.find_one()
# more read operations
```

but it turns out that the connection didn't read anything from secondary replicat set, no connection log could be found in mongo log on these 2 secondary replica set

Comment: Which version of pymongo are you using? if using 2.x you need to use the MongoReplicaSetClient rather than just the MongoClient

Comment: it's so werid... MongoClient didn't support secondary reads
thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to configure a **[ReplicaSetConnection](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.2/examples/replica_set.html#replicasetconnection)** instead. For instance:

```
>>> db = ReplicaSetConnection("morton.local:27017", replicaSet='foo').test
>>> from pymongo import ReadPreference
>>> db.read_preference = ReadPreference.SECONDARY
```

Comment: Connection and RepliaSetConnection are pretty old now. They were deprecated as they used unsafe writes by default. 

MongoClient and MongoReplicasetClient replaced them in 2.4 and set a write concern of 1 by default to ensure that unsuccessful writes are caught.

Since 3.0 that has been deprecated in favour of just using MongoClient.



http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/changelog.html