# How to force reading from replicaset secondary member with PyMongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to connect to a MongoDB replicaset with PyMongo and to manually balance the reading load with `ReadPreference`.
The problem is that whatever I try with `MongoClient`, it always reads from `PRIMARY`.

I am using Python 2.7.6 and PyMongo 2.6.3 with `mongodb-10gen` 2.4.14 (all for legacy reasons) on Linux Mint 17.2.

My connection sequence looks like this (without the print, and with massive request on some collection of some database from the connection):

```
>>> from pymongo import MongoClient, ReadPreference
>>> HOST = "10.0.0.51"
>>> PORT = 49029
>>> print MongoClient(host=HOST, port=PORT, replicaset="rs02", readPreference=ReadPreference.SECONDARY)
MongoClient([u'XXXX-MNGO03664:49029', u'XXXX-MNGO03663:49029'])
```

This one would be the right way to go with PyMongo > 3, from what I have read. Unfortunately I am stuck with PyMongo 2.6.3, and I can only assume that this is why it doesn't read from secondary.

After a bit of digging, I found about `ReplicaSetConnection` (deprecated since PyMongo 2.4) and `MongoReplicaSetClient` (see e.g. [pymongo replication secondary readreference not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30542997/pymongo-replication-secondary-readreference-not-work) and [pymongo: Advantage of using MongoReplicaSetClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554764/pymongo-advantage-of-using-mongoreplicasetclient)), but it also doesn't seem to work for me, for different reasons though.

```
>>> print MongoReplicaSetClient(host=HOST, port=PORT, replicaset="rs02", readPreference=ReadPreference.SECONDARY)
MongoReplicaSetClient([])
```

The client doesn't seem to be able to see the members of the replicaset…
And of course when I start reading from this connection, it doesn't work.

```
>>> myConn = MongoReplicaSetClient(host=HOST, port=PORT, replicaset="rs02", readPreference=ReadPreference.SECONDARY)
>>> print myConn.someDB.someCollection.count()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 759, in count
    return self.find().count()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 640, in count
    **command)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 391, in command
    result = self["$cmd"].find_one(command, **extra_opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 604, in find_one
    for result in self.find(spec_or_id, *args, **kwargs).limit(-1):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 904, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 848, in _refresh
    self.__uuid_subtype))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 782, in __send_message
    res = client._send_message_with_response(message, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/mongo_replica_set_client.py", line 1631, in _send_message_with_response
    raise AutoReconnect(msg, errors)
pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect: No replica set secondary available for query with ReadPreference SECONDARY
```

Note that the same error appears when I try to read with `ReadPreference.PRIMARY`.

The weird thing here is that if I change the name of the replicaset to connect to, the client spots that it doesn't exist :

```
>>> print MongoReplicaSetClient(host=HOST, port=PORT, replicaset="rs42", readPreference=ReadPreference.SECONDARY)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/mongo_replica_set_client.py", line 742, in __init__
    self.refresh()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/mongo_replica_set_client.py", line 1135, in refresh
    % (host, port, self.__name))
pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: 10.0.0.51:49029 is not a member of replica set rs42
```

So I assume that in normal cases, it has a way to see that there is a replicaset here, and who are its members.

Comment: After some further digging, it appeared that it was only a firewall issue : the *replicaSet* members couldn't access the client.

What led me in the wrong direction was that when I used `MongoClient`, it seemed to be able to request the `PRIMARY`, and only failed when I used a `MongoReplicaSetClient`. It still doesn't really make sense to me because all the members of the *replicaSet* are protected by the same firewall.

Just posting that here in case someone has a similar problem.